# How do I get Big out of the Underpant King's throne?

Tags: tiny-and-big

I'm stuck at the end of "Buried", where Big is sitting in the throne, throwing rocks at me.

[image]

The radio once gave me a hint about elements and that I need to keep some and remove others, but I'm not sure what that means.

I've tried interacting with the big glowing towers surrounding Big, but to no avail.

**How do I get Big?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I can cut open those big glowing towers, but the top ~20% of the visible part of the tower is uncutable for some reason. It's best to just slice away at the middle and then yank to tower core out.